# Java Deserialization -- file is correctly written to but calling .available() on the ObjectInputStream with the same file path always returns 0

Tags: java, deserialization

First of all, I'm new to the site, and found it very helpful for having previous questions of mine that had already been answered, but I couldn't find anything about this specifically, so I hope this hasn't already been answered. This is for a game I'm making where RoadPanel.shopList is a static arraylist that holds all the shops in the map (and they are drawn and updated, etc. from here). shopIn has the same filepath as the file that is (correctly) written to while the game is running (I opened the file to make sure it was being written to properly). I don't know why it says that there are no available files to read from the InputStream, so I'm really stuck...

```
public static void loadGame() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException
{
    ObjectInputStream shopIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("src/save/shops.ser"));
    System.out.println("Available: " + shopIn.available());
    while(shopIn.available() > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("hit");
        Shop s = (Shop)shopIn.readObject();
        RoadPanel.shopList.add(s);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help,
pete.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is invalid. `available()` isn't a test for end of stream. See the Javadoc. And it isn't implemented for some streams, including `ObjectInputStream`.

You should read until `EOFException` is thrown.

Comment: Oh, ok. I've tried that, however, and my arrayList isn't being loaded into. I've checked the size of the arrayList and it's still 0 after the loadGame() method is called... Sorry if these are dumb questions.

Comment: You've tried what? Exactly? And *what* `ArrayList`?